# Grep pattern file - filter duplicate hits on patterns

Tags: grep

I have a pattern file that I use with grep going through some logs, but since the patterns appear on multiple places in the logs, I get very long output. All I want is one line only for each of the patterns from the pattern file.

For example,

*patternfile*

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

*Logfile*

```
12 AAA
23 BBB
45 BBB
67 DDD
89 BBB
```

So `grep -f patternfile Logfile`, I'd get

```
12 AAA
23 BBB
45 BBB
89 BBB
```

But all I really want is

```
12 AAA
23 BBB
```

Not sure how to pipe this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

here is a perl program that does what you want:

pgrep.pl  [patternfile] [ logfile ]

caveat is the patternfile doesn't have wildcards

pgrep.pl ---

```
#/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

sub usage
{
    print "usage: $0  [patternFile]  [logFile ]\n";
    exit;
}

sub load
{
   my $file = shift;
   open my $input, "<", $file or die "unable to open $file : $!";
   my @data=<$input>;
   close $input;
   foreach ( @data )
   {
       chomp;
       s/\cM//g;
       s/^\s+//;
       s/\s+$//;
   } 
   return @data;
}
my $patternFile = shift or &usage();

my @patterns = &load( $patternFile );

my $logFile = shift or usage();

my @data = &load( $logFile );

foreach my $p ( @patterns )
{
    next if not length $p;
    my ($found ) = grep {/$p/} @data;
    print $found,"\n" if $found;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This `awk` one-liner can help:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}($2 in a){print $0; delete a[$2]}' pat log
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat pat
AAA
BBB
CCC
```

```
$ cat log
12 AAA
23 BBB
45 BBB
67 DDD
89 BBB
```

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]++;next}($2 in a){print $0; delete a[$2]}' pat log
12 AAA
23 BBB
```

**or**

```
$ grep -f pat log | sort -uk2
12 AAA
23 BBB
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
grep -f patternfile Logfile > tempvar; awk '!a[$0]++' tempvar
```